# Change ESM export bindings

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I'm wondering how the exported bindings of an ES6 module work when destructuring. I'm exporting an object (`thing`) as a named export -- but also one of its properties (`foo`), too, which I'm later updating.

This update works when I import the object and reference its prop, but not when I directly import `foo`, as shown below.  I'm guessing the `export const...` creates a new, immutable binding, but is there any way to retain its reference to the original object upon export?

```
// module: 'thing.js'

let thing = {
  foo: (x) => console.log(x)
};

const init = () => {
  thing.foo = (x) => console.log("updated");
};

export { init, thing };
export const { foo } = thing;
```

```
// index.js

import { foo, thing, init } from "./thing";

init();

foo("test");        // does not work
thing.foo("test");  // update is reflected, here
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/admiring-keldysh-o7ckds?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not issue with export/import

see this example:

```js
let thing = {
  foo: (x) => console.log(x)
};

const init = () => {
  thing.foo = (x) => console.log("updated");
};

const foo = thing.foo;

init();
foo("test"); //test
thing.foo("test"); //updated
```

Variable *foo* and field *thing.foo* contains different functions after you rewrite *thing.foo* inside init function

Comment: Ah, right you are!